# Java for loop bug

Tags: java, for-loop, applet

```
Image probe;

Thread t;
public int x=410,y=250;

public void init()
{
    //Images Call
    probe = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"image/probe.png");

    t = new Thread();   
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        g.drawImage(probe,x,y,50,50,this);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        System.out.print(i);
        x=x+10;
        y=y+10;
        repaint();

        try
        {
            t.sleep(100);
        } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

So in this it should do my for loop 5 times correct? but instead it does it over and over and over and never stops when i want it to just move 5 times then stop, but instead it just goes on forever.

Comment: Yes, the magical for loop which isn't in a method or static block. A unique creature to find in the wild.

Comment: 'it' does 'what', over and over and over?  Could you make your question more descriptive, please?

Comment: Where does the for loop live in? Your loop looks fine.

Comment: What you have pasted is not valid Java. It shouldn't even compile!

Comment: Sorry, my loop is in my "paint" method. I want it to run 5 times then stop.

Comment: @DaltonMetzler post the whole unmodified code.

Comment: @Krroae27 this is the whole unmodified code http://pastebin.com/zuVvdZYw

Comment: show us the whole paint method

Comment: @11684 http://pastebin.com/zuVvdZYw

Comment: Don't link us to pastebin. Edit your answer and put the code in there. For completeness it's not nice to link people to other sites so they can understand your question on SO.

Comment: is the code gets compiled `for(int i=0;i<;i++)` there is no restriction for `i` here.

Comment: Never call `repaint()` from within the paint method, and never call `Thread.sleep(...)` there either unless you want your program to be as unresponsive as possible. For that matter, you shouldn't call Thread.sleep within the GUI event thread either. Run, don't walk to the tutorials as you're doing several big issues wrong.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<;i++)`, i< what??

Comment: Also Thread's `sleep(...)` method is a static method, and so if you would want to use it (but you shouldn't here!), you'd call it on the class, not on a Thread instance. You will want to read the tutorial using a Swing Timer since that will help you do your animation. Also search this forum for examples of Swing animation -- some are good, and others are ones I've written. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your loop is in the `paint()` method and you call `repaint()` from within the loop you will cause the method to be called continually! You loop isn't executing over and over, it's executing once and then calling itself to be called again.

Comment: and on pastebin he's comparing i to nothing like for(int i = 0; i<; i++;)

Comment: I have another question. http://i45.tinypic.com/fkbscn.png Why does it keep the picture there? Can you help make it so it will not keep putting the image behind it?

Comment: @11684 That wasn't a prob I deleted that by accident.

Comment: @DaltonMetzler, [it is a prob if you are posting this code for other people to see, and you want them to find a bug in it](http://sscce.org). How are we supposed to find the bug you are looking for, if you put in some more errors which prevent even compiling it? This time you were lucky because the bug was obvious. You may not be so lucky next time.

Answer (score 0):

If you call [repaint()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) within your `paint()` method, it will keep calling `paint()` over and over again.